# Macro expansion ordering in tables

Tags: tables, macros

I've a large table (about 300 entries). Sometimes, I've a sequence of entries with the same value (for a given column). In such a case, I need to omit the value. All my values are stored in variables used elsewhere, and thus, I cannot simply get rid of them. To overcome that, I created a temporary command to maintain my value. Testing my solution in plain text gives me the desired result. However, when I apply my solution in a table, the results are wrong.

MWE (I put a dot to better see where the omited values are):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\myval}{}

\newcommand{\setMyVal}[1]{\renewcommand{\myval}{#1}}

\newcommand{\printOnlyFirstOccurence}[1]{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\myval}{#1}}
        {.}
        {\setMyVal{#1}\myval}%else
}

Outside table:

\printOnlyFirstOccurence{a}

\printOnlyFirstOccurence{a}

\printOnlyFirstOccurence{b}

\printOnlyFirstOccurence{b}

\printOnlyFirstOccurence{b}



Behaviour inside table:

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|c} \hline
    \printOnlyFirstOccurence{a} & a \\ \hline
    \printOnlyFirstOccurence{a} & a \\ \hline
    \printOnlyFirstOccurence{b} & b \\ \hline
    \printOnlyFirstOccurence{b} & b \\ \hline
    \printOnlyFirstOccurence{b} & b \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

In the above example, outside the table I got:

a
.
b
.
.
.

Inside the table I got:

a
a
.
.
.

Can someone explain this behavior?

Comment: Alignment cells form groups, so the redefinition of `\myval` is forgotten as soon as you go to another cell. Use `\gdef\myval{.}` instead of `\renewcommand{\myval}{#1}` in the definition of `\setMyVal`

Comment: Thank you @egreg, your comment helped to solve my MWE. I can update my question to include a more realistic use case, where I get another behaviour, now when using the biocon package. I'm new using stackexchange, thus, if it is more common, I can accept your answer (if you post it) and create another question, instead of updating this one.

Comment: could you please post your edit as a separate question ? It introduces new-elements (non expandable `\plant` command) which changes the context.

Comment: @jfbu, done in: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292751/macro-expansion-and-biocon-package

Comment: @egreg Could you post your comment as an aswer? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alignment cells form groups, so the redefinition of `\myval` is forgotten as soon as you go to another cell. Use `\gdef\myval{.}` instead of `\renewcommand{\myval}{#1}` in the definition of `\setMyVal`. With `\renewcommand` you only get a local redefinition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\myval}{}

\newcommand{\setMyVal}[1]{\gdef\myval{#1}}

\newcommand{\printOnlyFirstOccurence}[1]{
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\myval}{#1}}
        {.}
        {\setMyVal{#1}\myval}%else
}

Outside table:

\printOnlyFirstOccurence{a}

\printOnlyFirstOccurence{a}

\printOnlyFirstOccurence{b}

\printOnlyFirstOccurence{b}

\printOnlyFirstOccurence{b}



Behaviour inside table:

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|c} \hline
    \printOnlyFirstOccurence{a} & a \\ \hline
    \printOnlyFirstOccurence{a} & a \\ \hline
    \printOnlyFirstOccurence{b} & b \\ \hline
    \printOnlyFirstOccurence{b} & b \\ \hline
    \printOnlyFirstOccurence{b} & b \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]